# any software similar to my lockbox to lock particular file or software without encryption.similar to andriod applock for windows

Tags: open-source, lockscreen

I wanted to lock some file/folder and exe. I am trying to find software to lock the exe or folder without encryption. An open source alternative would be better. I have found my lockbox but it seems it has some malware,  so I looking for something else which could be free and open source.

Comment: What platform is this for ?

Comment: what does "lock the exe or folder" *mean*, functionally, to you, Priyan? What does "locking" do?